# Get Category Image to front-end from custom category attribute created through attribute manager

Tags: category, magento1.9.2.3

I have just created a custom attribute for categories through Attribute Manager, with attribute code `category_view_img`.

Now I can only put one image into a category, and use this image for both the banner and category-view-image on the home page. I want to use this custom attribute image on the home page as category view image. How can I get this image on front-end?

I am new to Magento and I don't have ideas how to do this, please assist. I am using Magento 1.9.2.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spinning my head regularly throughout all over Internet, I finally found a solution for this issue:

```
var $image= trim(Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$_category->getData('category_view_img'));

<img src="<?php echo $image;?>"/>
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
<?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load('category-id'); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $category->getCategoryViewImg(); ?> />
```

Comment: Thanx For Your Reply @Prashant, I have tried this, But its not working. Maybe there is any other way to getData from Catergory Attributes.